# Nested IF Statement in SQL Script

Tags: if-statement, nested

Here is my SQL script and I want the code to check if ExitPermissionNo Column has no CCS_Reference then Update the column with new CCS_reference number and If ExitPermissionNo already has a CCS_Reference number then give an error message stating "Already in Database" and If ExitPermissionNo was not found, give an error message " The ExitPermissionNo Not Found". I wrote it like this and it does not work with all 3 conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ((SELECT ExitPermissionNo FROM ExitPermission WHERE (ExitPermissionNo = '333333333'))!=1)
begin
if (SELECT 'CCS_Reference' FROM ExitPermission WHERE 'CCS_Reference' IS NULL )=1
begin
    PRINT 'Already In DataBase'
end
else
begin
    UPDATE ExitPermission
SET CCS_Reference = 'joon'
WHERE ExitPermissionNo = '333333333';
    PRINT 'The ReferenceCCS Update Successfully!'
end
end
else
begin
PRINT 'The ExitPermission Not Found!'
RAISERROR('The ExitPermission Not Found!',18,1)
end
```

Comment: Did you try the separate Select statements, to see whether they gave the expected results? (I doubt it) Please show any error message. (And do that as edit to your question)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks. It does not give any error. The problem is that I am not getting the right results.  it always shows "The ReferenceCCS Update Successfully" error message and "The ExitPermission Not Found" and NEVER check for "Already in dataBase" section.